No route matches Error in Controller and Router using Ruby on Rails MVC
I am new to ruby on rails. And I am trying to test one simple record pull example using Active Record. I am getting the following error while giving action from router to controller to get some article details using ruby on rails framework,
No route matches [GET] "/home/1"
My router file content like the following,
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check
get "service-worker" => "rails/pwa#service_worker", as: :pwa_service_worker
get "manifest" => "rails/pwa#manifest", as: :pwa_manifest

resource :pages do
 get 'home' => 'pages#home'
end
end

controller pages_controller.rb like the following,
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def home

    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

 end
end

Home.html.erb view file look like the following ,
<div>

 <p> <% @article.title  %> </p>
 <p> <% @article.description  %></p>

</div>

And this file is under views/pages folder.
Can anyone suggest or guide me to resolve this error please? or give any documentation to refer?

There is no route defined that matches a /home/1 path. What are defined are routes like pages/1 which would raise a different error, because there is no show method in the PagesController and pages/home.

Short answer
Instead of
resource :pages do
  get 'home' => 'pages#home'
end

use
get 'home/:id', to: 'pages#home'


its working according to suggested modification.

Why not just learn how the framework is intendended to be used?
The convential way to define the resource would be:
resources :articles 

Which defines the routes:
~/p/sandbox_7 (main)> rails routes -c articles
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy

Showing an article would thus be handled by:
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /articles/1
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end

While you can define non-RESTful routes like the typical "static pages" that an app will have you should be aware of what rules you're breaking and more importantly why you're breaking the rule.

Thank you for your response. I tried in that way only earlier. when I got error I choosed this cutom way. Can you please check the following url. This error is becasue of this suggested method in my same controller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79177961/routes-are-not-getting-available-using-resources-in-rails

What is it that your confused about? The comment from engineersmnky says everything. Your putting the wrong url into your browser. The accepted answer isn't very good.
